# SimpleDateFormat different behaviour depending on java version

Tags: java, date

In the netty framework there is the following code:

```
final class CookieDateFormat extends SimpleDateFormat {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1789486337887402640L;

    CookieDateFormat() {
        super("E, d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the above's output varies depending on the version of the jvm when I run it.

- on java 1.6 I get: Wed, 22-May-13 09:11:41 GM
- on java 1.7 I get: Wed, 22-May-2013 09:11:14 GMT

Is there any way to change the behavior on java 1.6 to match the output of 1.7 without having to alter the code (since I would prefer not having to change code in netty).

Comment: Does it change if you use a different jvm to run it?

Comment: I have the jdk 1.6 VM and the jdk 1.7 VM ... it changes when I change the VM.

Comment: unfortunately neither the 1.6 or 1.7 spec says anything specific about use of `y` in date formats. I would suggest to bite the bullet and recompile with `yy` or `yyyy` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `d-MMM-yyyy` instead of `d-MMM-y`. I hope that difference in seconds (41 vs 14) is your typing mistake. Otherwise I cannot explain this difference.

Comment: I would like to fix it without modifying the code, since it is not in my own code but in a framework I am using.

Comment: It is the netty framework and it is open-source. I created an issue on their github project.